# AST rewrite rule with " * +" in antlr

Tags: antlr

I'm having a trouble about rewrite rule to convert from parsing tree into AST tree in antlr.

Here's my antlr code:

```
grammar MyGrammar;

options {
  output= AST;
  ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
  backtrack = true;
}


tokens {
    NP;
    NOUN;
    ADJ;
}

//NOUN PHRASE
np  :    ( (adj)*  n+ (adj)*  -> ^(ADJ adj)*  ^(NOUN n)+ ^(ADJ adj)* )
    ;


adj : 'adj1'|'adj2';
n   : 'noun1';
```

When I input "adj1 noun1 adj2" , the result of **parse tree** like this:

[image: parse tree]

But the **AST tree** after rewrite rule seem not exactly like the parse tree, the adj is double and not in order, like this:

[image: AST tree]

So my question is how can I rewrite rule to have a result like the parsing tree above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your noun phrase rule collects all the adjectives and copies them to both sides of the nouns because ANTLR can't automatically distinguish between one group of matched `adj`s and another.

Here is a break-down of the `np` rule:

```
np  :    ( 
           (adj)*  //collect some adjectives
             n+ 
           (adj)*  //collect some more adjectives 
               -> ^(ADJ adj)*  //all adjectives written
                  ^(NOUN n)+   //all nouns written
                  ^(ADJ adj)*  //all adjectives written again
         )
    ;
```

One way to separate the two groups is to collect them into their own respective lists. Here's an example, applied to rule `np`:

```
np  :    ( 
           (before+=adj)*  //collect some adjectives into "before"
             n+ 
           (after+=adj)*  //collect some adjectives into "after"
               -> ^(ADJ $before)*  //"before" adjectives written
                  ^(NOUN n)+   //all nouns copied
                  ^(ADJ $after)*  //"after" adjectives written
         )
    ;
```

This way ANTLR knows which `adj`s to write out before and after the `n`s.